# Is there any library in xamarin forms for handling network calls like volley/retrofit in android?

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to use REST Web Services in my Xamarin Forms project. Please, suggest me if there is any official DLL/library suggested by Xamarin or any NuGet package which can handle asynchronous web service calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very good 'automatic' type-safe and async client for REST requests named **refit** made by **paulcbetts** its inspired on retrofit.

[check it out](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit).

Comment: In Documentation it shows that it will only supports for some platforms. but i am expecting one to supports all platforms. also i am working on xamarin forms will this support ?

Comment: Yes. It support Xamarin.Forms, I'm currently using it. If i helped pelase mark my answer as correct.

Comment: while i am trying to install from nuget i am getting below error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Rest.Fody 1.0.9'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0

Comment: Please follow this thread in refit issue tracker: https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues/260

Comment: does it supports xml serialization ? also it i am not able to add it as dependency project.

Comment: @praveen only supports json.